# TableLayout related issue

Tags: android

I want to show an array of strings into table layout. Having following code.I am able to get the data into log file but table layout i am seeing nothing.

```
TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
     for(int current=0;current<cursor1.getCount();current++)
     {
         //create a table row
     TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
     tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     // create a text view for start time
     TextView sTime= new TextView(this);
     sTime.setText(values[current]);
     sTime.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
     Log.i("Data Check", values[current]);
     sTime.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     tr.addView(sTime);
     //add the table row into TableLayout
     tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     }
```

Comment: we're going to need your layout xml...

Comment: Got the issue but cant able to resolve it. whenever i change the value of setText to some static text it works fine but the thing is in my log i can see the values[current] works properly but in table layout it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long time after but it may help you or someone else.
Where you create the row and add layout params to it , use the following type of params

TableRow.LayoutParams NOT the TableLayout.LayoutParams